# How do I get length of input string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need help to calculate the length of input string until a certain limit. Say **Table A** has column **"description"** with data **"calculate; length of the input string"**.
I need to get the length of string till **";"** in this case length of string is **9**. How do I get this done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `position` function:

```
SELECT position(';' in description) - 1
  FROM table_a
;
```

See [§9.4 "String Functions and Operators" in *PostgreSQL 9.4.4 Documentation*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html).